# vba apply all borders to range

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me with my code. A have simple data to which I want to apply "All Borders". Number of rows will change

```
Sub Draw_Borbers()
Dim FO As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim AllRange As Range



Set FO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Order")

LastRow = FO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set AllRange = Range("A2:I2" & LastRow)

With AllRange.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0

    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is while I only have 361 non-empty row (based on column A), it gives me borders for 2361 rows.

I thought It is because of blanc rows and added

```
.Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

to previous macros, but it still gives me that odd number of rows.

In previous macros I copy-paste data from pivot table and delete some rows, but even full list consists of only 651 rows...

Would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: `Range("A2:I2" & LastRow)` you are adding Lastrow to `I2` & `361` -> `2361` :)

Comment: `Set AllRange = Range("A2:I" & LastRow)` you left an extra **2** in.

Comment: as they say - live and learn) thank you very much!